# Use PostgreSQL JSON column type with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

The following migration in Rails 3 works:

```
class CreateUserActions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :user_actions do |t|
      t.datetime :time
      t.integer  :user_id
      t.text     :action
      t.column   :details, :json
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'user_actions'
  end
end
```

...but `schema.rb` is now incomplete reporting

```
# Could not dump table "user_actions" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'json' for column 'details'
```

So `rake db:reset` will fail to create the user_actions table.

Answer (score 8):

From: https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore just set the following in application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Now structure.sql will be used instead of schema.rb to create the database from scratch with `rake db:reset` or `rake db:prepare` and will be specific to PostGres.

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know this was possible.